# Opening MMC Block Device in Android Kernel Causing Crashes

Tags: android, linux, drivers

I'm writing a driver for the Android kernel which needs to open and eventually read from the MMC block device (e.g. "/dev/block/mmcblk0"). Right now I'm trying to open the block device using blkdev_get_by_path() and plan to read from it by constructing a bio struct for my read and using generic_make_request() to perform the read.

At this point I'm taking it one step at a time and only trying to open the device and then close it once it's successfully opened (with blkdev_put()). The problem that I'm facing is that even just calling blkdev_get_by_path() is sometimes causing the kernel to crash and reboot the device.

Here's a bit of code:

```
#define MMC_DEV "/dev/block/mmcblk0"

void open_mmc_dev()
{
     struct block_device *mmc_dev;
     mmc_dev = blkdev_get_by_path(MMC_DEV, FMODE_READ, 0);
     if (!IS_ERR(mmc_dev))
     {
          blk_dev_put(mmc_dev);
          printk("Opened MMC Device\n");
     }
     else
     {
          printk("blkdev_get_by_path failed with %ld\n", PTR_ERR(blk_dev));
     }
}
```

I should also add that this code for opening the MMC device is being run repeatedly, by scheduling an event with mod_timer(), initially scheduled within my own driver's init function. The reason for this is that the MMC device is not initially present, so I set up this event to run every 100ms. As long as blkdev_get_by_path() is returning -ENOENT I reset my event to run again 100ms later until I successfully get the block_device pointer. What I'm seeing is that 1 out of every 3 or 4 boots will either hang the phone or cause it to reboot. On the successfull boots I'm able to verify with dmesg that I was eventually able to get a pointer to the MMC block_device. I've also tried repeatedly running my event without the calls to blkdev_get_by_path() and blkdev_put() and this doesn't cause the crashes I'm seeing, so the crash appears to be related specifically to those blkdev calls.

What could be causing blkdev_get_by_path() to crash?
Is there some synchronization component I'm missing required for opening a block device like this?